# Invalid handle with Mail sender with Windows 7

Tags: perl, email, windows-7, 64-bit, mail-sender

Im using Mail::Sender with my perl program and were able to send mails with this program when using windows xp. After migration to Windows 7 this does not work anymore and fails with the following error:

```
error sending mail, connect() failed: The handle is invalid
```

Someone an idea how to handle this invalid handle error?

Comment: Are you sure that the server you are connecting to is (1) operational and (2) not blocked by some firewall?

Comment: not sure but we are testing that at the moment but as we can ping the server it seems that it is not blocked

Comment: Don't ping, telnet to port 25 and type some commands.

Answer (score 0):

Is every dependency installed right?

Did you tried to reinstall Mail::Sender or upgrade it to the latest version?

Did your perl version changed?

Is your old Windows XP was 32bit and the new one is 64bit?

Did you recompiled all the modules/perl or just copied over from old host?

This module is a pure perl module, if it dependency installed right then it should work on both windows.

Regards,

Comment: the old one was 32 bit and the new one is 64bit, is there a problem with that?

Comment: If you did not reinstalled the perl and every module, then yes, it is. Many Perl module uses C code (XS) and may use DLLs and that needs to be recompiled.